# Local state stores residing in kafka stream instances not getting synced in case of failover of one instance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am running multiple kafka stream consumer instances (2 instances) in my local machine, each having its own custom local store and each with different name.

As per documentation if one of the instances goes down then kafka has to sync the store of dead instance to the store of instance which is alive (correct me if I am wrong).

I have configured both instances with same application id to let kafka know these instances belong to same group.

When one of the instances are killed then the store of other (alive) instance is not getting synced with the store of dead instance. I have enabled change log topic on both stores.

How-ever when I have same store name in both instances, stores getting synced as expected, not sure if these instances are pointing to one store.I have different StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG location for these two instances.

Please let me know if I am missing something, can store name be different on different instance of application? Does kafka automatically takes care replaying change log topic on new instance store?

//below is my stream configuration

```
@Bean
public KafkaStreams kafkaStreams(KafkaProperties properties,
                                 @Value("${spring.application.name}") String appName) {
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, appName);
    props.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "client2");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, properties.getBootstrapServers());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 0);
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerde.class);
    props.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10 * 1000);
    //props.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "/tmp/kafka-streams1");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.NUM_STANDBY_REPLICAS_CONFIG, "1");
    props.put(StreamsConfig.consumerPrefix(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG),
            new RoundRobinAssignor().getClass().getName());
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");
    final KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(kafkaStreamTopology(), props);
    System.out.println("Invoked kafkaStreams");
    //kafkaStreams.cleanUp();
    kafkaStreams.start();
    return kafkaStreams;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am running multiple kafka stream consumer instances (2 instances) in my local machine, each having its own custom local store and each with different name.

This sounds incorrect. If you run multiple instances with the same `application.id` (ie, `group.id`), all instances *must* execute the same code. (I am wondering why your application does not crash in the first place.)

I am not 100% sure what you try to achieve. It might be helpful if you could share your topology code?

Note that KafkaStreams shards logical stores base on the number of input topic partitions (cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html). Maybe you confuse sharding with logical stores?

If you want to have two logical stores, each with one shard, you can still run multiple instances and the stores will be executed on different instances (and fail-over will work too). However, you still need to "include" both stores on both instances on startup.